# How to transfer auto generated grid to grid with individual columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, multiple-columns

Actually I am using the auto generated grid function like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserDataObject}" Width="786" />
```

Now I'd like to specify the individual columns like

```
<DataGrid>
    <Column Header="ID" />
    <Column Header="Username" />
    <Column Header="Role">--Show Role As Selector--</Column>
</DataGrid>
```

How does this work in WPF?

Explanations:

My UserDataObject is defined as

```
ObservableCollection<User> mUserDataObject = new ObservableCollection<User>();

public ObservableCollection<User> UserDataObject
    {
        get
        {
            return mUserDataObject;
        }
    }

    //User user = new User("ID", "Username", "Password", "Role");

    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Attributes
        private int? _ID;
        private string _Username;
        private string _Password;
        private string _Role;

        // Constructors
        public User()
        {
        }

        public User(int pID, string pUsername, string pPassword, string pRole)
        {
            this.ID = pID;
            this.Username = pUsername;
            this.Password = pPassword;
            this.Role = pRole;
        }

        // Getter and Setter
        public int? ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; OnPropertyChanged("ID"); }
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get { return _Username; }
            set { _Username = value; OnPropertyChanged("Username"); }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _Password; }
            set { _Password = value; OnPropertyChanged("Password"); }
        }

        public string Role
        {
            get { return _Role; }
            set { _Role = value; OnPropertyChanged("Role"); }
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Additionally, how can I add an event listener that registers changes in one cell?

Comment: I edited your title to remove the tags. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) for the reasoning behind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set **`AutoGenerateColumns`** to **`False`** on dataGrid and provide your own list of columns.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding UserDataObject}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username}"/>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Role" ItemsSource="{Binding Role}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Use `DataGridTextColumn` if want to allow user to edit the property and `DataGridComboBoxColumn` if want user to select value from only permissible values for the property.

---

> how can I add an event listener that registers changes in one cell?

Since you have proper bindings, you don't have to worry about handling it in code behind. Move your code to property setters to which cell is binded to.

However, in case you are interested you can hook **`CellEditEnding`** event.

Comment: My grid becomes totally empty trying your approach. I changed Binding="{Binding ID}" to Binding="{Binding UserDataObject/ID}" which also fails...

Comment: Is `ID` property exist in underlying source class?

Comment: Yes, it exists. My ObservableCollection owns a User object that has a property ID.

Comment: Try `UserDataObject.ID` in that case. If it doesn't work please post the code for your collection, I would like to see the property structure.

Comment: Nothing. The grid stays empty. I added the code for my collection.

Comment: Can you post code for `User` class? Ideally it should work fine.

Comment: I added the whole User class above.

Comment: Class seems perfect. If you set `AutoGenerateColumns = True`, data is visible in that case? Make sure you set `ItemsSource` properly in both cases and collection has items in it.

Comment: With the following declaration my binding works as expected but it is auto generated: <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserDataObject}" Width="786" />

Comment: You have to set `ItemSource` still like this - `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding UserDataObject}">`. Earlier I missed setting `ItemsSource`, updated in the answer. Does that work?

Comment: Also `Role` property is of type `String`. So you have to declare 3rd column as DataGridTextColumn like this - `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Role" Binding="{Binding Role}"/>`. Earlier you posted you want it to be selector type so I was assuming you're `Role` property was of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Now it is beeing displayed but the combobox remains empty. Yes, actually role is a string but it should become an enumeration with one selected item.

Comment: It seems you are confused with what you want. `Role` is of type `String` so how can it fill combobox? With auto generating columns too, it must be a text column. So either make `Role` of type `IList<String>` or make column a DataGridTextColumn if you want it to be plain text like other columns. `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Role" Binding="{Binding Role}"/>`.

Comment: Yes, absoultely. Many thanks. But I have to open another seperate question on updating cells.